# document.write in IE

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I haven't checked with IE9 but I have a simple JS that utilizes document.write to display some information. It works on every browser except IE 6, 7, 8. I checked all my other code and when I decided to eliminate all of it and simply put

```
document.write(Testing);
```

I got nothing from IE. Is there another command I can use. I am new to Javascript.

Comment: Not an answer.. but it sounds like you may want to spend some quality time with jQuery...

Comment: Add quotation marks around `Testing` and see what that does.

Comment: `Testing` is an undefined variable. But you should not use `document.write` anyway. Create a new DOM element instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how your original code is using document.write, but you could achieve more or less the same effect this way:

```
<div id="outputGoesHere"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("outputGoesHere").innerHTML = "Testing";
</script>
```

Comment: And if you wanted to be really DOM-y you could say `document.getElementById("outputGoesHere").appendChild(document.createTextNode("Testing"));`, but I'm guessing that you'd be better off with the simpler method for now.

Comment: I am having trouble with sizing my document in IE and lower resolution monitors. So I put together some Javascript to get the screen width and height and display it on the page. It works fine in all the browsers except IE. I used the DOM-y method and it worked just fine. Thanks.

Comment: If I were to put a new div id in my css called #outputGoesHere and place the tag somewhere in my html would I be able to add the JS to the <script> at the begining of the html?

Comment: @totbar - If the <script> tag appears before the <div>, you need to make sure it doesn't get run until after the <div> has been loaded. You could put it inside of a function that gets called onload, attach it to an onload event, put it inside a setTimeout function, or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

try: `document.write('Testing');`

Answer (score 1):

We were having this problem earlier today and luckily our page already had access to jquery...

Replacing `document.write(variableWithYourValue)` with `$('html').html(variableWithYourValue)` did the trick for us.